# How can I add my python code to my django web app?

Tags: python, html, django

So I'm building a website using django and what it's supposed to do is detect emotions in real time, like there should be a button to start and stop detecting and it will use the device's webcam. I've already built both the django project and app and written the python code to do that but i wrote them separately.

The problem comes when I'm trying to add the python code to my web app views.py and template(html). This is my code, could someone help me out?

```
#mood detection python code
import cv2
import numpy as np
from deepface import DeepFace

def detect_emotions():
    face_cascade_name = cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
    if not face_cascade.load(cv2.samples.findFile(face_cascade_name)):
        print("Error loading xml file")

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (48, 48), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(resized_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = gray_frame.astype('float32') / 255.0
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

        analyze = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions=['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (200, 30), (0, 0, 0), -1)
        first_data = analyze[0]
        dominant_emotion = first_data['dominant_emotion']
        text = str(dominant_emotion)
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Real-time Emotion Detection', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    detect_emotions()
```

```
#views.py
def detect_mood(request):
    # Call your mood detection function
    results = detect_emotions()

    return JsonResponse(request, 'mood_detection/home.html', {'results': results})
```

```
<!--html template-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Real-time Emotion Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Real-time Emotion Detection</h1>
    
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>

    <script>
        // Get access to the user's webcam and set up the video stream
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                var video = document.getElementById('video');
                video.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding the mood_detect() function to the views.py directly but I don't think I added it correctly. Also the funtion is showing a window, I also have to add a window for the webcam using JavaScript, is there anyway this two are conflicting? If so, what can I do to solve this problem?

Currently, it's showing the mood detection window separately, I want it to show on the webpage itself like the other web apps online.

Comment: I believe webcam data captured will be streamed to your server in real time. Am I correct?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon yes, exactly. So it will be capturing the emotions at the same time they're happening.

Comment: Then use [Django Channels library](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It supports streaming which Django doesn’t support natively well.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: No, I couldn't implement the channels library as suggested. I'm not experienced to that level yet, I just wanted an easy to understand solution. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Use [Django Channels library](https://channels.readthedocs.io/) so that you can support streaming easily and efficiently. Your infinite while loop here `while True:` should be in a [`consumer`](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#consumers) method not in a regular `view` because `views` adopt the *request-response cycle* of **Http/1.1**.

[Here is a tutorial on how to use Django Channels.](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html#tutorial)